# Azure Active Tenant Federation Metadata

Tags: azure, active-directory, multi-tenant

I got azure AD url like below,

login.windows.net/7229xd0-5227-41c8-8459-c0819kj6718/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml

My web config file:

[image]

This is my `startup.Auth` Page

public partial class Startup
    {

```
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

    string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context => 
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

But I got error page[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o733A.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your application to the identifier 632485c9- does not seem to be mapped to make use of the AD that you are trying to connect through.

Please go the portal.azure.com and then navigate to the directory and ensure that the app you are using is mapped to the AD and also user mapping can be verified.

[image: Error Message]